# Tortoise and Hare simulation terminating issue

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<time.h>
#include<ctime>
#include<iomanip>
using namespace std;

const int End=70; //constant fixed integer for the entire game.

void MoveTurtoise (int *); 
void MoveHare (int *);
void PrintPosition (int *, int*);



int main()
{
int Tortoise = 1;
int Hare = 1;
int Time = 0;

srand(time(0));

cout<<"BANG!!!!!\n"
    <<"AND THEY'RE OFF !!!!!\n";

while( Tortoise != End && Hare != End )
{
    srand(time(0));
    MoveTurtoise (&Tortoise);
    MoveHare (&Hare);
    PrintPosition (&Tortoise,&Hare);
    Time++;

}

if (Tortoise==Hare)
        cout<<"It's a tie."<<endl;
    else if (Tortoise>Hare)
        cout<<"Tortoise wins."<<endl;
    else if (Hare>Tortoise)
        cout<<"Hare wins."<<endl;

system("PAUSE");
return 0;
}

void MoveTurtoise (int *Tortoise)
{
srand(time(0));
int p = 1+ rand()%10; // 1 <= i <= 10

if (1<=p && p<=5) //Fast plod
    Tortoise+=3; //3 squares right
else if (p>=6 && p<=7) //Slip
    Tortoise-=6;//6 squares left
else //Slow plod
    ++Tortoise; //1 square right

if (*Tortoise<1)
    *Tortoise=1;



}

void MoveHare (int *Hare)
{
srand(time(0));
int p = 1+ rand()%10; // 1 <= p <= 10

if (1<= p && p<=2); //Sleep
                    //No move
else if (p>=3 && p<=4) //Big hop
    Hare+=9;//9 squares right
else if (p==5) //Big Slip
    Hare-=12;// 12 squares left
else if (p>=6 && p<=8) // Small hop
    ++Hare;// 1 square right
else if (p>=9 && p<=10)// Small Slip
    Hare-=2; // 2 squares left

if (*Hare<1)
    *Hare=1;


}

void PrintPosition (int *Tortoise, int *Hare)
{
if (Tortoise==Hare)
    cout<<"OUCH!!!"<<endl;
else if (Tortoise<Hare)
    {
    cout<<setw(*Tortoise)<<"T"<<endl;
    cout<<setw(Hare-Tortoise)<<"H"<<endl;
    }
else if (Hare<Tortoise)
{
    cout<<setw(Tortoise-Hare)<<"T"<<endl;
    cout<<setw(*Hare)<<"H"<<endl;

}




}
```

Hello all. I just made a code for Tortoise and Hare simulation game in C++. I am having an issue finding what is causing my program to "not" terminate. It is keep going on and on with same result. I am assuming there's a looping error and a wrong usage of srand()..but I still have no clue...

Comment: Have you tried debugging it? Are `Tortoise` and `Hare` incrementing? Are they reaching 70? Over 70?

Comment: I debugged and all I see was T and H repeating with same result.

Comment: I don't think you need to use `srand` in every function. Just use it once in `main` and remove the `srand` in the loop since you already have one before it

Comment: As a hint - you're looping while the tortoise and hare aren't exactly at the end. What if one of them goes too far?

Answer (score 1):

In the functions `MoveTurtoise` and `MoveHare`, you are incrementing the pointers not their values.

```
void MoveTurtoise (int *Tortoise)
{
   srand(time(0));
   int p = 1+ rand()%10; // 1 <= i <= 10

   if (1<=p && p<=5) //Fast plod
      Tortoise+=3; //3 squares right
      // This makes Tortoise point to a different location.
      // It does not change the value of what Tortoise points to.
      // Similarly for the next two clauses.

   else if (p>=6 && p<=7) //Slip
      Tortoise-=6;//6 squares left
   else //Slow plod
      ++Tortoise; //1 square right

   if (*Tortoise<1)
      *Tortoise=1;
}
```

What you need:

```
void MoveTurtoise (int *Tortoise)
{
   srand(time(0));
   int p = 1+ rand()%10; // 1 <= i <= 10

   if (1<=p && p<=5) //Fast plod
      (*Tortoise) += 3; //3 squares right
   else if (p>=6 && p<=7) //Slip
      (*Tortoise) -= 6;//6 squares left
   else //Slow plod
      ++(*Tortoise); //1 square right

   if (*Tortoise<1)
      *Tortoise=1;
}
```

`MoveHare` needs to be fixed in a similar manner.

Here's a better solution. Change change the argument type to `int&` and then the code will more like what you have.

```
void MoveTurtoise (int& Tortoise)
{
   srand(time(0));
   int p = 1+ rand()%10; // 1 <= i <= 10

   if (1<=p && p<=5) //Fast plod
      Tortoise+=3; //3 squares right
   else if (p>=6 && p<=7) //Slip
      Tortoise-=6;//6 squares left
   else //Slow plod
      ++Tortoise; //1 square right

   if (Tortoise<1)
      Tortoise=1;
}
```

Also, your implementation of `PrintPosition` is as if the arguments were:

```
void PrintPosition (int Tortoise, int Hare);
```

which is a better than what you have. Change

```
void PrintPosition (int *Tortoise, int *Hare);
```

to

```
void PrintPosition (int Tortoise, int Hare);
```

Answer (score 0):

yes, user3543568198 
you forgot to add header library using std::setw; and you added a else if (Hare<=Tortoise) in your print statement contradicting the if else since if... else do the same thing but your codes pass by reference looks all good except your Tortoise function is missing the raceEnd=.... in both hair and Tortoise functions.... just by replacing your programs functions with the functions below it will actually move the units accross the screen... oh be sure to add
const int RACE_END = 70; in header

```
void MoveTurtoise (int *Tortoise)
{
int x = 1 + rand() % 10;
// determine which move to make
if (x >= 1 && x <= 5)        // fast plod
    *Tortoise += 5;

else if (x == 9 )   // slip
    *Tortoise -= 12;

else                           // slow plod
    ++(*Tortoise);
if (*Tortoise < 1)
    *Tortoise = 1;

else if (*Tortoise > RACE_END)
    *Tortoise = RACE_END;

}



void MoveHare(int *Hare)
{
int y = 1 + rand() % 10;
/* Write statements that move hare */
// determine which move to make
if (y >= 1 && y <= 5)        // fast plod
    *Hare += 3;

else if (y == 6 || y == 7)   // slip
    *Hare -= 6;
else                           // slow plod
    ++(*Hare);

/* Write statements that test if hare is before
the starting point or has finished the race */
if (*Hare < 1)
    *Hare = 1;

else if (*Hare > RACE_END)
    *Hare = RACE_END;
}
```